# nested loop optimisation

Tags: matlab, loops, nested

I'm really struggling to optimize a calculus code on MATLAB.

It's a heavy calculation required to obtain the material properties of a non-linear material.

This calculation requires more than 240 millions steps.
It's rather simple in itself as it consist in a huge number of `sum`.
The only problem is that the numbers are stored in various arrays and lists which is a bit confusing.

Here is the original code :

```
Tensor=zeros(3,3,3,3);
for m=1:3
    for n=1:3
        for o=1:3
            for p=1:3
                for x=1:16 
                    for y=1:16
                        for z=1:16 
                            for i=1:3
                                for j=1:3
                                    for k=1:3
                                        for l=1:3
                                            for r=1:3
                                                for s=1:3
                                                    sum=sum+(1/(8*(pi()^2))*P{x,y,z}(i,m)*P{x,y,z}(j,n)*P{x,y,z}(k,o)*P{x,y,z}(l,p)*(TensorC(i,j,k,l)-TensorC0(i,j,r,s))*TensorA(r,s,k,l)*sin(omega(x))*p_omega(x)*p_phi(y)*p_beta(z);
                                                end
                                            end
                                        end                                                    
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
                Tensor(m,n,o,p)=sum;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`P{x,y,z}(i,m)` is a change of basis formula (same for the others) : `i and m` determine the type of formula and the result is calculated with the `x`, `y` and `z` variables.

All the other numbers in the summation are real numbers picked up in arrays and tensors.

I tried to extract as much variables from the last for loop in order to calculate them as soon as possible an reduce the number of operations:

```
Tensor=zeros(3,3,3,3);
CO1=1/(8*(pi()^2));
for m=1:3
    for n=1:3
        for o=1:3
            for p=1:3
            sum=C0_tensor(m,n,o,p);
                for x=1:16
                    CO7=sin(omega(x));
                    CO8=p_omega(x);
                    for y=1:16
                        CO9=p_phi(y);
                        for z=1:16
                            CO10=p_beta(z);
                            for i=1:3
                                CO2=P{x,y,z}(i,m);
                                for j=1:3
                                    CO3=P{x,y,z}(j,n);
                                    for k=1:3
                                        CO4=P{x,y,z}(k,o);
                                        for l=1:3
                                            CO5=P{x,y,z}(l,p);
                                            CO6=TensorC(i,j,k,l);
                                            for r=1:3
                                                for s=1:3
                                                    CO11=TensorC0(i,j,r,s);
                                                    CO12=TensorA(r,s,k,l);
                                                    sum=sum+CO1*CO2*CO3*CO4*CO5*(CO6-CO11)*CO12*CO7*CO8*CO9*CO10;
                                                end
                                            end
                                        end                                                    
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
                Tensor(m,n,o,p)=sum;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Still, the calculation is much too long.

I don't see any way of parallelizing or vectorizing the calculation ...

The operation of retrieving one particular value from one array or one matrix seem to be very slow...

Do you think I should build a huge tensor containing all the values instead of using multiples one?

Comment: If really hard to avoid for loops, you should start to consider using other programming languages which favors looping, like `C++`

Comment: 8o         ...good gracious... and good luck. Do you already have a large dependency on matlab code?

Comment: Quantify *much too long*.

Comment: On the scientific theory side, there is no way of avaiding thoses loops ... But I think I can find a way to cut half of the calculation thanks to the symmetry of some matrix. Now the loop runs in 9min instead of 2h (i've optimized the arrays and tensors structure). If I want to go faster, I'll have to switch in C++. We'll see in a few days if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name as you're overwriting the useful function by the same name.

Taking just the inner loop here, you're calculating a single value for each `r` and `s` which is added to your output value:

```
  for r=1:3
         for s=1:3
              CO11=TensorC0(i,j,r,s);
              CO12=TensorA(r,s,k,l);
              sum=sum+CO1*CO2*CO3*CO4*CO5*(CO6-CO11)*CO12*CO7*CO8*CO9*CO10;
         end
  end
```

However, you could at once get C011/C012 as 3 x 3 matrices, do one sum and then add that to your output:
(changed your `sum` to `out` here, note the .* rather than * in the appropriate place):

```
C011 = squeeze(TensorCO(i,j,:,:));
C012 = squeeze(TensorCO(:,:,k,l));
s = CO1*CO2*CO3*CO4*CO5*(CO6-CO11).*CO12*CO7*CO8*CO9*CO10;
out = out + sum(s(:));
```

Also, when you do this:

```
CO7=sin(omega(x));
CO8=p_omega(x);
```

(which is just then C07*C08 in the later equation) - you don't need to recalculate sin(omega(x)) for every `n,m,p.`, so that can be taken out of the loop entirely.

Pre calculate `sin` and multiply by `p_omega` (outside loop):

```
omega78 = sin(omega).*p_omega;
```

Then just retrieve the value `C78 = omega78(x)` in the x-loop and use that instead of `C07*C08`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

I applied your ideas and tweaked a bit the maths and the arrays / tensors structure. 

Basically, the main loop is now 10x faster. 

I'll keep trying to find new ideas !

Comment: I optimized the tensors and arrays structure. 
Now the main loop runs in 9min instead of 2h !